# Post Infopath form data into SAP webservice after a SharePoint workflow

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sap, infopath

I have created a Infopath 2010 form and once a user submits the form it is published to a Sharepoint document library. Then it goes through an approval process and approver either can confirm or reject.

And my question is:
Once a form is accepted, how can we send the form data into a webservice. I have created the service in SAP and I want to consume that service and send the form data. That service is to return an error or success message according to the posting done in SAP and I want to inform user with this message as well..

Thank you !!!

Comment: I guess the question is valid for calling any Webservice, whatever it's originating from SAP software or any other one...

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box activities set in SharePoint is limited. To call a web service you need to build your custom activity or use one built by others already:

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Call%20a%20Web%20Service%20Action

Also: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/